# I need help to make this code work

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to run different scripts for mobile and desktop users for that I use the Mobble wordpress plugin that lets me use is_handheld(); to detect handheld devices. I'm pretty new to this so can you please tell me where did I do wrong? It gives an error. Thanks

```
    <?php 
        if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) :
    ?>
    <?php 
        if ( !is_handheld() ) {
       echo"<script type="text/javascript" src="/source1"></script>”;
    }
      else {
       echo"<script type="text/javascript" src="/source2"></script>”;
    }
    <?php 
        endif;
    ?>
    <?php 
        endif;
    ?>
```

Comment: why are  you closing / opening php unnecessarily and  why are you using .php source for javascript script? do you just want to make this code correct?

Comment: I'm not a programmer.. I put this code head to head from what I found o the internet. Help me with it if you can :)

Comment: The scrip is actually an ad code. It is php. I just stripped it to focus the question on the rest

Answer (score 1):

This should resolve your errors

```
      <?php 
         if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) :
            if ( !is_handheld() ) {
              echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="/source1"></script>';
           }
            else {
             echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="/source2"></script>';
           }
          endif;
        ?>
```